# OpenLayers with custom polygons: problems with ol.geom.LinearRing

Tags: openlayers-3

I´m converting a simple ASP.NET application from OpenLayers 2 to **OpenLayers 3**.

This applications makes use of a custom-defined Vector Layer - i.e. a Vector object that I fill up with my custom multipolygons. I basically call a stored procedure and I fill a variable called "polyline", based on which I should be able to create my **ol.geom.LinearRing** object.

The problem is that, by creating the LinearString object, I get the following error:

> AssertionError: Failure: unsupported stride: undefined

here is my code:

```
for (var i in polyline)
{
    var coord = polyline[i];
    var point = new ol.geom.Point([coord.x, coord.y]).transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913"); 
    sitePoints.push(point);
}
linearRing = new ol.geom.LinearRing(sitePoints);
```

I´ve also tried to explicitly specify the **GeometryLayout**, till now with no results.

```
linearRing = new ol.geom.LinearRing(sitePoints, ol.geom.GeometryLayout.XY);
```

By manually checking the code and surfing the web I´ve realized the problem might be in a bug in the `setCoordinates()` function of the `ol.js` library (I´m currently using `ol-debug.js` v.3.5.0). But I have no idea how to fix it / which workaround I could make us of.

Any help would be warmly appreciated.

g4lvuz

Comment: EPSG:900913 is nonsense. this should be EPSG:3857 in OL3. Can you provide a jsFiddle or provide us with a sample geometry and I can fork a jsFiddle with the sample for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the hint - I'm new to Javascript and I never used jsFiddle, but I´m gonna give a look now.

Comment: here is a sample of the "polyline" I want to use: polyline = 
[
 {x: 16.37376206, y:48.19958029}
 , {x: 16.37385355, y:48.19959905} 
 , {x: 16.35548841, y:48.21036004}
 , {x: 16.35531591, y:48.20966506}
 , {x: 16.35519314, y:48.20921214}
 , {x: 16.37337628, y:48.19965110}
 , {x: 16.37376206, y:48.19958029}
];

Answer (score 2):

it seems that linearRing constructor expects an array of coordinates, not of Points.

try change your

```
sitePoints.push(point);
```

into

```
sitePoints.push(point.flatCoordinates);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/ao4759pL/) for the polyline which you provided in the comments section.

You mention multi-polygons? You want to give me an example multipolygon or are you fine with the jsFiddle alone.

You will create geometries from the coordinate pairs.

Then apply a transformation to the geometry using a transformation function with you can get from [ol.proj.getTransform()](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html#getTransform).

```
tranformFn = ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
featureGeometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(
    [[[16.37376206, 48.19958029],
    [16.37385355, 48.19959905],
    [16.35548841, 48.21036004],
    [16.35531591, 48.20966506],
    [16.35519314, 48.20921214],
    [16.37337628, 48.19965110],
    [16.37376206, 48.19958029]]]
);

featureGeometryTf = featureGeometry.applyTransform(tranformFn);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Actually your way to create ol.geom.Polygons objects works and seems much easier to implement. I´m gonna try it with multipolygons, but it shouldn't be a problem. I'm actually still having some troubles while trying to add the feature to the vectorLayer object: vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures([multiPolygonFeature]);

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to make the ASP.NET + Javascript code work with OpenLayers 3. Here is a code snippet:

```
tranformFn = ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913'); // 'EPSG:3857'
var featureMultiGeometry = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(null);
@{
    foreach (var item in modelGeographieMultiPolygon.Select(x => new { geoKennung = x.geoKennung, Bezeichnung = x.Bezeichnung, Vorfahren_geoKennung = x.Parent_geoKennung}).Distinct()) // for each region
    {
        <text>        
        @*
        siteStyle =
        {
            strokeColor: "#000000", // #770077
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
            fillColor: getRandomColor(),
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            pointRadius: 20,
            label: $("<div/>").html("</text>@item.Bezeichnung<text>").text(),
        };
        *@
        siteStyle = new ol.style.Style
        ({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill
            ({
                color: [255, 155, 255, 0.5]
            })
        });
        </text>

        foreach (var PolID in modelGeographieMultiPolygon.Where(x => x.geoKennung == @item.geoKennung).Select(x => x.Polygon_ID).Distinct()) // for each polygon
        {
            int count = 0;
            <text>featureGeometry = new ol.geom.Polygon([[</text>                   
            foreach (var punkt in modelGeographieMultiPolygon.Where(x => x.geoKennung == @item.geoKennung && x.Polygon_ID == PolID.Value)) // for each point in the polygon
            {
                if(count!=0)
                {
                    <text>, </text>;
                }
                <text>[</text>@punkt.Ecke_Longitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".")<text>, </text>@punkt.Ecke_Latitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".")<text>]</text>
                count++;
            }
            <text>]]);
            featureMultiGeometry.appendPolygon(featureGeometry);
            </text>;
        }
    }
}

featureMultiGeometryTf = featureMultiGeometry.applyTransform(tranformFn);

var multiPolygonFeature = new ol.Feature
({
    geometry: featureMultiGeometry
})
;
geometryMultiPolygonFeatureArray.push(multiPolygonFeature);
vectorLayer.getSource().addFeatures(geometryMultiPolygonFeatureArray);
```

Thank you to everybody for the help! Your answers turned to be really useful to me.